# How does this function work the other way?

Tags: c, function, for-loop, while-loop, do-loops

Obviously, if we write 'x < 10' then, x is smaller than 10. However, it's not the case here

```
int n;
do
{
    n = get_int("width");
}
while (n < 10);


for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("?");
}
printf("\n");
```

If we wanted to print '?' the same number as the user input, it will only print when numbers are larger than 10 while it shouldn't. Because n is not smaller than 10... the loop shouldn't run.

So how is that possible?

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean here. The first (`while`) loop will run until the user inputs an number greater than or equal to 10; the second (`for`) loop will run as long as `i` is less than that given `n` - it will start with `i = 0` and increment `i` each time.

Comment: Did you possibly intend to have the `for` loop *inside* the `while` loop? (As a way of indicating to the user that the input is unacceptable.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be fundamentally a question about basic logic or reasoning, rather than a question about the code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...*it will only print when numbers are larger than 10 while it shouldn't.*

Why shouldn't it? The first loop gets an `int` from the user, if the user inputs a value that is smaller than 10, it will continue asking the user for a new input, if the user inputs a value larger than or equal to `10` the `while` loop will end and `n` will have the input value, then the `for` loop is executed, if `n` is, for example, `15`, it will run `15` times and consequently print `?` 15 times.

Answer (score 0):

The While continue loop until n Is less than 10. Only when n Is 10 or more your program exit from while loop and print.

Comment: The `while` loop continues **while** `n` is less than 10, not **until** `n` is less than 10.